# Get subtotal of inputs and then add

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle that adds the total of the inputs perfectly and changes as the inputs change.
But I also need it to take into account the quantity of each item.

So the current total is $105 but it should be it should be $235, taking into account the Qty of 3 items that are $65.

Checking out the fiddle will show you what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/4n7k012b/1/

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var sum = 0;
                //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
                $("input[class='cmb_text_money']").each(function () {
                    //add only if the value is number
                    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                    }

                });

            $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));

            $(document).on('keyup',"input[class='cmb_text_money']", function () {
                var sum = 0;
                //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
                $("input[class='cmb_text_money']").each(function () {
                    //add only if the value is number
                    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                    }

                });

            $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
            console.log(sum);

            });
        });
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the code which takes into account the quantity as a multiplier.  It seems to be doing exactly what it is told which is simply summing the value of the amount text boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do that, traversing up to the quantity and then multiplying with the price, storing each sum in an array that is then summed up at the end

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input.cmb_text_money, input.cmb_text_small', function () {
    var sum = $.map($('input.cmb_text_money'), function(item) {
        return $(item).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('input').val() * item.value;
    }).reduce(function(a, b) { 
        return a + b; 
    }, 0);

    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/4n7k012b/3/)